# XMLHttpRequest do not work used in messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(...) for receiving a feedback when my webapp receive a message from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to receive a feedback with a rest call when firebase send a message to my webapp. I was able to do it when the webapp is in foreground with this code in the file [index.html]:

```
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
   createNotification(payload);
   sendFeedbackToFirebaseRest(payload);
});

function sendFeedbackToFirebaseRest(payload) {
    var internalID = payload.data.internalID;
    myBody = {
          "internalID": internalID  
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "http://192.168.10.181:8083/firebase-rest/androidMessage", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("internalID="+internalID);
    console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

I was not able to do the same when the app is in background (I'm wathcing a page of another web site for example). However my code is (in the file firebase-messaging-sw.js):

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  sendFeedbackToFirebaseRest(payload);
  return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title, {
    body: payload.data.body
  });
});
```

XMLHttpRequest work in index.html (included in tag script of course) but give me error "is not defined" in the other file. There is a solution for this problem?

I refer to:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

But I'm using it without the firebase command (just a simple web page).

Basically I want to call an API on my server but I could not find a way to do it. 
Any advice will be appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not use XMLHttpRequest in a thread worker in javascript. For this reason I have to use Fetch:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

For example:

```
postData('http://example.com/answer', {answer: 42})
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
 // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
})
.then(response => response.json()); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects 
}
```